# Apache storm nimbus service unable to start

Tags: ubuntu, apache-storm

While running nimbus service of Apache storm on Ubuntu 18.01. I am getting the message

> Need python version > 2.6

I already have Python 3.6.5 installed on the machine?

Comment: Please show the actual content of the error message you receive

Answer (score 0):

Nimbus is specifally dependend on Python 2.6.6. So installing Python 2.7 would probably be the best option for you.

Python 3 wasn't yet fully tested with Apache Storm. Check out the ["Setting up a Storm Cluster" tutorial](http://storm.apache.org/releases/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be sure that you have python version superior to 2.6.

Then go to the storm file (not storm.*) and look at the variable PYTHON change it to your python exe path, and it will work
Good luck